# How to get installed application name in android?

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

I have made a small method to display the installed application name in android. But when i give "name" attribute its showing exception error. And when i give "packageName" the method executes perfectly and displays the package name in a list

```
private void getInstalledApps() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     PackageManager packageManager=this.getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo applist=packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);


        Iterator<ApplicationInfo> it=applist.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            ApplicationInfo pk=(ApplicationInfo)it.next();

            String appname=pk.name.toString();

            installedapplist.add(appname);
        }

}
```

In the above code when i give `String appname=pk.packageName.toString()` it works fine but when I give `String appname=pk.name.toString()` the program is throwing an exception error. Please help me to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My guess is your code is throwing a NullPointerException because the `name` field is null. In any event, what you probably want is:

```
String appname = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(pk).toString()
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @charlag_khan - You mean `pk.name`? Probably because the manifest doesn't declare an `android:name` attribute. That name is only used when the app needs to define it's own `Application` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

by using this you can get installed app package names and app names

```
List<PackageInfo> packageInfos=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (PackageInfo packageInfo:packageInfos)
{
        Log.d(TAG,"packageName "+packageInfo.packageName);
        Log.d(TAG,"appname "+getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo));
}
```