# How to initialise Context in order to get the names of installed applications?

Tags: android, android-context

I am trying to make a program to get the names of all installed applications. In my Activity, I have a method called `getApplicationNames` that should return this information:

```
private ArrayList<String> getApplicationNames(Context context){
    ArrayList<String> nameOfRunningApps = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ApplicationInfo> runningApplications = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo: runningApplications){
        nameOfRunningApps.add(applicationInfo.name);
    }

    return nameOfRunningApps;
}
```

Now I want to call this method in `onCreate()`:

```
ArrayList<String> installedProgramNames = getApplicationNames(??);
```

How do I make an instance of `Context` in order to call this method? Is this even possible?

Comment: `ArrayList<String> installedProgramNames = getApplicationNames(this);` if you call method in onCreate() of Activity class

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick!

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838348/6414086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Activity]

Since `Activity` is basically extending `Context` in the hierarchy, you can easily achieve your requirement as follows inside `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ArrayList<String> installedProgramNames = getApplicationNames(this);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android the `Activity` class extends `Context` (see the heirarchy diagram at the top of the [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)), so you can pass a self-reference to your activity into `getApplicationNames` via the `this` keyword, i.e.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<String> installedProgramNames = getApplicationNames(this);
}
```

This is also true for other variations of `Activity` such as `AppCompatActivity` from the support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Using the application context will do the job.

```
ArrayList<String> installedProgramNames = getApplicationNames(getApplicationContext());
```